# R: function that returns a vector of unique integers with multiple occurrences

Tags: r

Prompted: 
Given a vector of integers, write a function that returns a vector of those unique integers with multiple occurrences and put the result in a data frame.

I do not know how to isolate integers with multiple occurrences.  Perhaps using the **unique** function?

I guess I would then want to display the results with something like:

```
table()
as.data.frame(table())
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps you can consider posting a reproducible example with sample input and output?

Comment: Without getting tricky, `result <- as.data.frame(table(V.ints))` gets you nearly all the way there. If you select out the rows where `Freq >= 2` you're done.

Answer (score 1):

```
> sample(1:10, 10, replace=TRUE) -> x
> x
 [1]  5  3  2 10 10  5  9  5  5  6
> y <- rle(sort(x))
> y$values[y$lengths > 1]
[1]  5 10
> y$lengths[y$lengths > 1]
[1] 4 2
```

Or using `table`:

```
> table(x)[table(x) > 1]
x
 5 10 
 4  2
```

Comment: I'm surprised the `rle` solution is actually pretty quick.